# Can't install lsb-core on Ubuntu Server 11.10

Tags: ubuntu

I'm attempting to install lsb-core on an Ubuntu server. Did `apt-get update` then did `apt-get install lsb-core`

```
root@quackwall:~# apt-get install lsb-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lsb-core : Depends: lsb-invalid-mta but it is not going to be installed or
                     mail-transport-agent
            Depends: binutils but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                     libc-dev
            Depends: cups-bsd but it is not going to be installed or
                     lpr
            Depends: lprng or
                     cups-client but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: m4 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: mailx or
                     mailutils but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: make but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ncurses-term but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: pax but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: alien (>= 8.36) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So apparently Ubuntu doesn't feel like installing `lsb-core`. The one thing I can find on Google says that there mirror was out of date. However I can't find what's wrong with my sources.list. Below is a copy of it

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111011)]/ oneiric main restricted

#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-Server 11.10 _Oneiric Ocelot_ - Release i386 (20111011)]/ oneiric main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu oneiric partner

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Ubuntu's
## 'extras' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu oneiric main


###################
# MODS
###################

# Webmin
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

Now I'm not entirely sure if that's good or not, but I know that I can run basic updates just fine. And since I'm using the US mirror, it shouldn't be out of date.

Any idea's on what's wrong?

Comment: Does `apt-get -s dist-upgrade` say your system is up-to-date?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, I ran it before I tried to install it

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/apt/preferences` file?

Comment: @Gilles No, but I do have an empty preferences.d directory

Comment: you made may day!
Thx so much for sharing - had the same issue ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, figured it out on my own. But I think what might of been the problem is that I didn't explain things well in the question

I've installed the hamachi Linux beta using `dpkg -i package.deb`. For some reason dpkg didn't install dependencies, which made apt panic. Manually installing didn't work.

However, it appears as you need to run `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` to get the depedencies working. Then it matched everything and hamachi worked

Comment: +1 for `apt-get -f dist-upgrade`. That solved it for me!